# Expectation of card computations without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you have 13 cards labelled 1 to 13. You draw 3 cards at random *without* replacement and make the following calculations:

1. Take the product of the 3 cards and set this equal to x
2. Take the absolute difference of the squares of the first and second card (ignoring the third card) and set this equal to y

The objective is to calculate the EV of x and y. I am able to do this via computation by going through the different permutations. However, I was wondering if there is any quicker way to do it? The reason I ask is that I was asked this problem in a time pressured setting which made me think that either I was supposed to estimate the answer, or there may be a quick way to get to an exact answer. Is there an intuitive explanation for why the expected value of the product without replacement is slightly lower than with replacement?

The method that I have used so far is the following. For calculating E(x):

- The expected value with replacement would be 7^3. Therefore, you can do 13^3 * 7^3 and subtract the sum of all the instances when two or more of the numbers are equal (there are 13 instances when all 3 are equal, and 3 x 13 x 12 = 468 instances when 2 are equal; once you subtract all these cases you are left with the expected value of the product of drawing without replacement)

For calculating E(y):

- I have just run a script to compute the difference of squares for all 152 combinations of the first and second card, but not sure if there is a quicker way

Comment: Well, $E[y]=0$ by symmetry unless you meant absolute difference.

Comment: As for the intuition question, note that eliminating $13\times 13\times 13$, say, has * a lot* more impact than ruling out $1\times 1 \times 1$.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if, once you resolve the issue pointed out in @lulu's comment, it turns out that the idea of the problem was to use the result of the second question in answering the first, since what you need to quickly compute the answer to the first question is $\langle xy^2\rangle=\langle x\rangle\langle y^2\rangle=7\langle y^2\rangle$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, absolute difference thanks. Edited

Comment: Take the average of $xyz$ and $(14-x)(14-y)(14-z)$, then you only need the averages of $x$ and $xy$

Comment: Then $(12\mathbb{E}(xy)+\mathbb E(x^2))/13=(\mathbb E(x))^2$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the computation of $E[Y]$.  I expect there is a more elegant argument, but this one isn't so very terrible.

We consider the problem for $n$ cards numbered $1$ through $n$ and let $Y_n$ be the relevant random variable in each case (so the problem is asking for $E[Y_{13}]$)

Claim:  $E[Y_n]=\frac {(n+1)^2}3$

Pf:  (induction).  Easy to argue for small $n$.  Suppose we have shown it for $n-1$ and consider the case $Y_{n}$.  There are $\binom n2$ equally likely unordered choices for the first two cards.  Of these, $n-1$ involve card $\#n$.  Inductively, the average of the other $\binom n2-(n-1)$ is $\frac {n^2}3$  Thus $$E[Y_n]\times \binom n2=\left(\binom n2-(n-1)\right)\times \frac {n^2}3+\sum_{k=1}^n (n^2-k^2)$$

and, somewhat messy, algebra confirms the induction.

Note:  a similar approach shows that $$E[X_n]=\frac {n(n+1)^2}8$$  Though in that case the algebra is so messy that I really can't imagine that this was the intended approach. I had to do the cases up to $X_7$ by "hand" just to spot the pattern. Still, I thought it worth recording the general solution.  I have no doubt that thinking through the algebra would streamline it considerably, but there ought to be a combinatorial argument.